# Constraints not updating and view is letterboxed when rotating device

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, orientation, nslayoutconstraint

**Background:**

When rotating the device, the view `myView` becomes letterboxed instead of resizing to fit the screen, see image below.

On the storyboard, `centreX` and `centreY` constraints are set.

In the code, `width` and `height` constraints are set with the function `viewAddConstraints()`, see code below.

After the device is rotated, I call `viewAddConstraints()` again, but Xcode gives the following error: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`

---

**Questions:**

How do I correctly remove old constraints and then add new constraints when the device is rotated?

How do I correctly update the constraints of a view when the device is rotated?

---

**Code:**

```
func viewAddConstraints() {

// Width constraint full width of screen
        let myViewWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView as Any, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.bounds.width)
        myView.addConstraint(myViewWidth)

// Height constraint full height of screen
        let myViewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView as Any, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.bounds.height)
        myView.addConstraint(myViewHeight)

}
```

---

**Image:**

*Current situation, view is incorrectly letterboxed.*

[image]

*Intended situation, view resized correctly.*

[image]

Comment: You remove the existing constraints by keeping references to them (usually as instance properties) exactly so that you have something to deactivate. In other words instead of just creating `myViewWidth` and `myViewHeight` and throwing them away after activating them, _store_ them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to set constraints to keep your subview "pinned" to the sides:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    ])
    
}
```

Or, since you should be respecting the **Safe Area**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)
    
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
        myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
        myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
    ])
    
}
```

Now your subview will automatically resize to fit its superview on device rotation.